# How can I get the attributes of certain tags in xml file?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file(.graphml actually) and I would like to access the attributes of the `node` tag, because I only want to tamper those nodes that has the `yfiles.foldertype="group"`. One specific part of my file looks like this and I am looking for a tag like that in the 3rd line.[Here is the whole file in case it matters :)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19HDKeccCuSt4k4uV73QBudHVqsd175SQ/view?usp=sharing)

```
 <graph edgedefault="directed" id="G">
    <data key="d0"/>
    <node id="n0" yfiles.foldertype="group">
      <data key="d4" xml:space="preserve"/>
      <data key="d6">
        <y:ProxyAutoBoundsNode>
          <y:Realizers active="0">
            <y:GroupNode>
              <y:Geometry height="112.37646484375" width="90.0" x="489.0" y="288.62353515625"/>
```

I have tried this code and it simply does not find any of the `node` tags. However if I try the same on any other tags that starts with a `y:`(eg.:`y:Realizers`), it works. The only tags it does not find are the one without `y:`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('unnamed6.graphml').getroot()

ns = {'y': 'http://www.yworks.com/xml/graphml'}

for node in root.findall('.//node', ns):
    value = node.get('id')
    print(value)
```

Comment: 'y' is a namespace prefix. As such, it shall be declared in the XML. Without it the XML is not well-formed.

Comment: There should be one or more `xmlns` attributes on the root element (`<graph>`) of your document. Are those actually missing or is that a copy-and-paste error?

Comment: You have ignored the fact that the document uses a default namespace `xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"`. The node element therefore needs to be qualified with a namespace prefix.

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate of one specific question, but if you search for "XPath default namespace" you will find thousands of other people falling into the same trap.